# Show/hiding <video> container produces pluginApi errors - mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have two video elements on one page, each within its own div.  I have a set of links that each have a jQuery click event that shows/hides the corresponding divs.  When these divs are shown/hidden, the following errors occur in Firefox and Chrome:

this.pluginApi.pauseMedia is not a function (FF)
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'pauseMedia' (Chrome)
this.pluginApi.playMedia is not a function (FF)
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'playMedia' (Chrome)

When I remove the video elements from their container divs and use a jQuery click event to merely pause/play, the errors do not occur.

[Demo using div containers](http://bit.ly/J8sNuC)

[Demo with no div containers](http://bit.ly/KAz2Vf)

Does anyone have experience showing/hiding video containers for mediaelements.js?

Answer (score 0):

For those still interested: I'm experiencing this behaviour also but have the following comments:

It only happens with the flash player, not with html5 video player for mp4.
It does not happen in IE

The play error's look like a timing issue because I could solve them with:

```
$('#div1').show(function(){
        player1.play();
});
```

I did not solve the pause error yet